# Why does the "Shortcut key" for Windows shortcuts stop working?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I have several shortcuts in my Start Menu folder, with the shortcut key set.

Some of the keyboard commands periodically stop working.  The only remedy I know is to delete and recreate the shortcut.

I think this problem goes back to the late 90's.

It's described pretty well (but not resolved) [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/34091-custom-keyboard-shortcut-key-not-working-properly.html).